# How to provide an extendable WPF ContextMenu with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I’m building a user control that has a context menu with several items, and I want the users of that control to be able to append items to that context menu.

I thought of adding an attached property where users can specify menu items, but I couldn’t find a way to easily add these items (e.g. in an ItemsControl container) to the control’s ContextMenu in an MVVM way (i.e. using binding and not code-behind).

Do you have an idea how this can be done?

Comment: whats the code you got so far?

Comment: Nothing much. I was hoping to get ideas here...

Comment: if your users can append the menu, then which handler will be fired onClick?

Comment: @Dilshod: The users will simply specify MenuItem objects, and these objects will contain Commands or Click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Dictionary<int,MenuItem>` and you will have a place that user can select menus. Then add selected menu items to `ContextMenu` when your control loaded.

I hope this helps.